# How to return a redirected URL in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I am working on verifying 301 redirects are functioning properly. I have a Google Sheet of URLs and have a Google script that checks the status being returned:

```
function getStatusCode(url){
   var options = {
     'muteHttpExceptions': true,
     'followRedirects': false
   };
   var url_trimmed = url.trim();
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_trimmed, options);
   return response.getResponseCode();
}
```

Next I am wanting to verify that the URL is being redirected correctly. This is where I'm getting stuck. I tried using a variation of the above code, but I can just return the URL being passed in, not the URL being redirected to, or I just get an error on my Google Sheet. Here is the last bit I tried using (that returns an error).

```
function getReturnedURL(url) {
   var options = {
     'method': 'GET',
     'muteHttpExceptions': true,
     'followRedirects': true
   };
   var url_trimmed = url.trim();
   var returnedUrl = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl(url_trimmed);
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(returnedUrl, options);
   return response;
}
```

Any ideas? Or, is this even possible?

Comment: I cannot understand the script of `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl(url_trimmed)`. Because `getUrl()` has no arguments. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/service#getUrl()) About this line, can you explain about what you want to do?

Comment: @Tanaike - I was playing around with the `.getUrl();` function and thought I read somewhere I could pass it in a value. The `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();` was returning `null` for me, so I was trying to pass it in the URL I was trying to retrieve.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I noticed that your issue was resolved. I'm glad for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So for my situation, I was wanting to pull a URL from a spreadsheet and return the redirected URL in a different column of said spreadsheet. @carlesgg97 put me on the right path, here is what ended up working for me:

```
function urlProtocol(url){
  return URI(url).protocol()
}

function urlHostname(url){
  return URI(url).hostname()
}

function getRedirects(url) {
  eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://rawgit.com/medialize/URI.js/gh-pages/src/URI.js').getContentText());

  var params = {
    'followRedirects': false,
    'muteHttpExceptions': true
  };

  var baseUrl = urlProtocol(url) + "://" + urlHostname(url),
      response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params),
      responseCode = response.getResponseCode();

  if(response.getHeaders()['Location']){
    var redirectedUrl = getRedirects(baseUrl + response.getHeaders()['Location']);
    return redirectedUrl;
  } else {
    return url;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot know what the final destination of your request is **only** from the [HTTPresponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response.html) obtained.

However, you can use the `getRedirects` function below to get the URLs that your request would follow upon calling `fetch` with `followRedirects` set as `true`:

```js
function getRedirects(url) {
  var params = {
    'followRedirects': false,
    'muteHttpExceptions': true
  };
  var followedUrls = [url];

  while (true) {
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
    if (res.getResponseCode() < 300 || res.getResponseCode() > 399) {
      return followedUrls;
    }
    var url = res.getHeaders()['Location'];
    followedUrls.push(url);
  }
}


function test() {
  var followedUrls = getRedirects('http://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/');
  Logger.log(followedUrls);
}
```

In this case, running `test` will return:

```
[http://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/,
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/,
https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1#]
```

Comment: this does work, but doesn't quite get me to where I wanted. I pulled in the help of a developer in house and he was able to figure it out. Posting the answer above

Comment: @Billy thanks for the script, but when i run that last code you posted i get this error report:

```Exception: DNS error: https://victo.ushttps://bitly.com/pages/landing/branded-short-domains-powered-by-bitly?bsd=victo.us (line 18).```

it seems to be combining the original URL and the final redirected one.

Answer (score 2):

There was a slight edit needed on Billy's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58801197/9758091) to make it work (remove "baseUrl + " from 6th last Line):

```js
function urlProtocol(url){
  return URI(url).protocol()
}

function urlHostname(url){
  return URI(url).hostname()
}

function getRedirects(url) {
  eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://rawgit.com/medialize/URI.js/gh-pages/src/URI.js').getContentText());

  var params = {
    'followRedirects': false,
    'muteHttpExceptions': true
  };

  var baseUrl = urlProtocol(url) + "://" + urlHostname(url),
      response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params),
      responseCode = response.getResponseCode();

  if(response.getHeaders()['Location']){
    var redirectedUrl = getRedirects(response.getHeaders()['Location']);
    return redirectedUrl;
  } else {
    return url;
  }
}
```